# tidymodels - error in fit_resamples using step_ns()

Tags: r, tidymodels

I'm trying to write a function that fits resamples off a recipe that uses step_ns(). For some reason I am getting the error messages:

`Fold01: recipe: Error: Not all variables in the recipe are present in the supplied training set`

and so on for all the folds. And then

Warning message:
`All models failed in [fit_resamples()]. See the` `.notes` `column.`

This is my code:

```
compare_basis_exp_to_base_mod <- function (data, outcome, metric, ...) {

  outcome <- rlang::enquo(outcome)
  metric <- rlang::enquo(metric)
  
  pred_list <- colnames(data)
  
  outcome_str <- substring(deparse(substitute(outcome)), 2)
  outcome_str_id <- which(colnames(data) %in% outcome_str)
  
  predictor <- pred_list[-outcome_str_id]
  
  data <- data %>% 
    rename(prediction = !!outcome)

  res <- tibble(splits = list(), id = character(), .metrics = list(), 
                .notes = list(), .predictions = list(), pred = character())
  
  rec_without_splines <- recipe(prediction ~ ., data = data) %>%
    prep()
  
  rec_with_splines <- recipe(prediction ~ ., data = data) %>%
    step_ns(all_predictors(), ...) %>% 
    prep()
  
  folds_without_splines <- vfold_cv(juice(rec_without_splines), strata = prediction)
  
  folds_with_splines <- vfold_cv(juice(rec_with_splines), strata = prediction)
  

  mod <- linear_reg() %>% 
    set_engine("lm")

  mod_without_splines <- fit_resamples(mod,
                                       rec_without_splines,
                                       folds_without_splines,
                                       metrics = metric_set(!!metric),
                                       control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(pred = "no_splines")
  
  mod_with_splines <- fit_resamples(mod,
                                    rec_with_splines,
                                    folds_with_splines,
                                    metrics = metric_set(!!metric),
                                    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(pred = "with_splines")

  res <- mod_without_splines %>%
    bind_rows(mod_with_splines)
  
  return (res)
}
```

Basically the argument `data` takes in a two column table and `outcome` is the name of the outcome column. Aside from the use of this function (I'm just playing around with tidymodels here as I'm new to it) I just want to understand what's causing this error and how to fix it. The error comes when evaluating `mod_with_splines`.

A similar problem was encountered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132850/recipesstep-dummy-carettrain-errornot-all-variables-in-the-recipe-are). But I don't know if it relates to my problem. I can't not prep the recipe before passing it to `fit_resamples`. (Or so I think)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from trying to apply a recipe on a dataset that has already been run through that same recipe.

If we assume that the predictor variables were `X1` and `X2`, then `rec_with_splines` is expected those variables. But since `folds_with_splines` contains the juiced results of `rec_with_splines` then `folds_with_splines` actually contains `X1_ns_1`, `X1_ns_2`, `X2_ns_1`, and `X2_ns_2`. Not `X1` and `X2`.

I would suggest using [workflows](https://workflows.tidymodels.org/) to combine the preprocessing and modeling step. And to pass the raw data into `vfold_cv()`.

```r
library(tidymodels)
compare_basis_exp_to_base_mod <- function (data, outcome, metric, ...) {

  outcome <- rlang::enquo(outcome)
  metric <- rlang::enquo(metric)
  
  pred_list <- colnames(data)
  
  outcome_str <- substring(deparse(substitute(outcome)), 2)
  outcome_str_id <- which(colnames(data) %in% outcome_str)
  
  predictor <- pred_list[-outcome_str_id]
  
  data <- data %>% 
    rename(prediction = !!outcome)
  
  rec_without_splines <- recipe(prediction ~ ., data = data) %>%
    prep()
  
  rec_with_splines <- recipe(prediction ~ ., data = data) %>%
    step_ns(all_predictors(), ...)
  
  mod <- linear_reg() %>% 
    set_engine("lm")
 
  wf_without_splines <- workflow() %>%
    add_recipe(rec_without_splines) %>%
    add_model(mod)
  
  wf_with_splines <- workflow() %>%
    add_recipe(rec_with_splines) %>%
    add_model(mod)
  
  data_folds <- vfold_cv(data, strata = prediction)

  mod_without_splines <- fit_resamples(wf_without_splines,
                                       data_folds,
                                       metrics = metric_set(!!metric),
                                       control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(pred = "no_splines")
  
  mod_with_splines <- fit_resamples(wf_with_splines,
                                    data_folds,
                                    metrics = metric_set(!!metric),
                                    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(pred = "with_splines")

  res <- mod_without_splines %>%
    bind_rows(mod_with_splines)
  
  return (res)
}

res <- compare_basis_exp_to_base_mod(mtcars, mpg, rmse)
```